# How to handle questions that morph into a completely different question?

Tags: discussion

I've seen this a number of times.  Someone asks a question that is pretty clear, and answers are provided that address that question.  But the question turns out to not be the whole story in terms of the problem the OP is having.  In fact, in some cases the question was misguided, and had nothing to do with the OP's problem.

So then the question turns into a completely different question in the OPs mind, and he/she starts adding a second question below the first one.  In most cases, the title of the question is not updated and so has no relation to the second question.  If valuable information and/or answers are provided to the second question: a) someone searching based on the title of the question won't find them, and b) answers will be posted that have nothing to do with the original title and question.

How does one deal with this situation, either while it is occurring or once it has already occurred?  I am tempted, when I see it happening, to ask the OP to post a second question.  I think this is the most direct question I have here.  Is that the proper thing to do?

Any other advice on trying to improve this situation in practice would be appreciated.

Comment: If the OP edits the question out from under provided answers, just raise a custom mod flag for *vandalism* and explain the situation. Usually the moderator will just revert the edits.

Comment: Highly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: My unfortunate experience has been that XY questions are often asked by people who are completely clueless, and attempting to help them just drags you deeper into the mire...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you do with it depends on the effect those changes have on the question, and if there is an existing answer to the question.

If there is no answer, any edits to improve the question should be accepted.

If the edits clarify the question (even if it moves away from the original question if there is not an answer), you can edit the title to make it more appropriate.

If it is a completely new question (like a follow up) you can encourage the OP to post a new question, possibly rolling back the changes.

If there is an existing reasonable answer, any changes that would invalidate that answer should be rolled back.  Keep in mind that clarifications are still acceptable, and the title can be changed to be more appropriate.  In some cases the question is vague, the edit clarifies the question and/or makes it more specific, and the answer is for a question that was not the objective of the post (answers what the answerer thought was the question, but turns out not to be).  These edits should stay, with possibly a comment on the question pointing out that the edit invalidates the answer.

If the OP insists on making changes that should not be made (and have already been rolled back), a comment to the user about why that shouldn't be done and/or can be posted.  Flagging for moderator attention should be a last resort.

Comment: `If there is an existing answer, any changes that would invalidate that answer should be rolled back.` - I disagree slightly.  Attempts to clarify an unclear question should be acceptable regardless.  Someone throwing up guess answers shouldn't be rewarded for guessing wrong

Comment: @psubsee2003 and even if he guess right. There was this Q&A pair on AU where the question had like 2 lines of something that didn't work with gnome, without indicating what was even wrong. No error message, no description of the problem. Another user answers something like "yeah, you should modify line X and change it to no" and was accepted. We discussed for like 30 minutes wondering what magic ball that user had that figured out the problem. Then closed the question as unclear and deleted it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I think the overall summary is "use your best judgement".  My main take-away is that I will not be too hesitant to step in and say "hey OP, why don't you make this new line of questioning a second question...".  In case anyone is interested, [here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893818/how-to-peform-sudo-commands-in-a-slurm-cluster-when-you-are-not-an-admin/55893864#55893864) that brought me here . The follow-up stuff fizzled, so this question is actually in good shape as it stands.